# Проблема с парсингом аргументов с argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Имеется одна проблема. Как можно при парсинге аргумента `-l 1,2,3,4` вернуть не строку, а список из этих чисел?

```
def get_args():
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest="list_for_bubble", help='List for Bubble Sorting')
    options = parse.parse_args()
return options
```

Comment: По-моему надо сделать опцию `nargs='+'` в `add_argument(...)`, и тогда `./script -l 1 2 3 4` вернет `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, но это не точно :) P.S. `type=int` не забудьте, если хотите прям инты :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо

```
return options
```

используйте

```
return options.list_for_bubble.split(",")
```

Значением `options.list_for_bubble` будет для вашего аргумента `-l 1,2,3,4`строка `'1,2,3,4'`, которую функция `split()` превратит в список `['1', '2', '3', '4']`.

Когда вы хотите вернуть список *чисел*, т.е. список `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, используйте команду

```
return [int(i) for i in options.list_for_bubble.split(",")]
```

или — более понятно — 2 команды

```
list_of_strings = options.list_for_bubble.split(",")
return list(map(int, list_of_strings))
```